# Using the hit-or-miss method to estimate the volume of a hypersphere centered at the origin in R

Tags: monte-carlo, simulation

I just need some help on how to get started on this problem, cant use any libraries and relatively new to R.
I understand it has to be a 2 for loops inside each other.

Comment: Please move question to stack overflow as this is not a math question.

Comment: As far as I know, this is actually a non-trivial question. The "obvious" approach --- generate a lot of random points in the hypercube $[-1,1]^d$ and count how many of them fall in the unit hypersphere --- doesn't work well in high dimensions because the sphere is such a tiny fraction of the cube.

Comment: I have seen 'hit or miss' used in several ways. @AndreasBlass has a point that the simplest interpretation is not promising. More context about specific applications you have studied recently would be helpful. Or showing what you may have tried (however pathetic).  Perhaps look at sections 4 and 5 of [_this_](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-086-numerical-computation-for-mechanical-engineers-fall-2014/nutshells-guis/MIT2_086F14_Monte_Carlo.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is the kind of implementation @AndreasBlass had in mind in his
Comment. It is only for $d = 3$ and won't work well for large $d$ because then the hit rate will be way too low. I'm using the unit sphere.

Perhaps
you can point out why this 'obvious' method doesn't match the level of your
course. It certainly doesn't have (overt) nested for-loops.

```
x1 = runif(10^6, -1,1);  x2 = runif(10^6, -1,1);  x3 = runif(10^6, -1,1)
inside = (x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 < 1)
mean(inside)
## 0.523128    # hit rate
8*mean(inside)
## 4.185024    # aprx volume of sphere
4*pi/3
## 4.18879     # exact volume of sphere
```

The following works for the unit ball in $d$ dimensions ($d$ not
too large), and the R code is a bit more elegant.

```
set.seed(2017)
m = 10^6;  d = 3;  x = runif(m*d, -1, 1)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=m);  r = rowSums(MAT^2)
2^d*mean(r < 1)
## 4.190264        # Monte Carlo
pi^(d/2)/gamma(1 + d/2)
## 4.18879         # Exact
```